# Как правильно последовательно вызывать pipe() при описании gulp-тасков с помощью TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, gulp, typescript

При описании gulp-таска с помощью TypeScirpt, эксперимента ради указал неверный возвращаемый для функции `pug()` html-препроцессора pug:

```
interface IGulpPlugins {
  pug: () => string;
}

import * as gulp from 'gulp';
import * as _gulpPlugins from 'gulp-load-plugins';

const gulpPlugins = _gulpPlugins();

export default class MarkupPreprocessingHelper {
  private preprocessMarkupFiles(globSelection: Array<string>) {

    return gulp.src(globSelection)
        .pipe(gulpPlugins.pug())
        // ...
  }
}
```

IDE подсказывает, что верный тип - WritableStream:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же мы изменим возвращаемый тип на WritableStream

```
interface IGulpPlugins {
  pug: () => WritableStream;
}
```

то получим такую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Наконец, когда мы изменим возвращаемый тип на `NodeJS.WritableStream`, ошибка из строки `.pipe(gulpPlugins.pug())` исчезнет. Но если мы последовательно вызовем следующий pipe (а по-другому быть не может - ведь нужно же куда то "положить" откомпилированные файлы), то получим ошибку о том, что у WritableStream не свойства `pipe`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не смыслю в Vynil, но если бы у того, что возвращает `pipe()`, нельзя было вызывать ещё один `pipe()`, то JavaScript тоже бы не работал. Что я упустил с типами?

Comment: `TransformStream`?

Comment: Такого типа не в списке автодополнений...

Comment: Тогда `ReadWriteStream`?

Comment: Это помогло! Благодарю Вас за ответ!